# PHP DOM - accessing newly added nodes

Tags: php, dom

I use the following to get a html document into DOM:

```
$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html)
```

and then I add some new content to an element in the html:

```
$element = $dom->getElementById('mybox');
$f = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$f->appendXML('<div id="newbox">foo</div>');
$element->appendChild($f);
```

But if I now want to manipulate the #newbox, I can't do it because I can't access it with `getElementById()`. In order to do that I have to do the following (reloading with the new html):

```
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
$dom->loadHTML($html)
```

Which works fine, but when having to do this between every dom manipulation, it becomes expensive performance-wise.

Is there any better way to "refresh" the DOM so that it works with the newly added elements?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm curious what answers will be provided to this; there has to be a proper way to do this, I guess... but can't think of anything right now. Minor detail in the question: the $dom variable is missing its dollar prefix in the dom->getElementBYId('mybox'); statement.

Answer (score 1):

On the save-and-load approach, you could also try [`Document.normalizeDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.normalizedocument.php). This should fix up the document as if it had been save-cycled, without actually really serialising. One thing that should do would be to re-calculate the [`isID`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domattr.isid.php)-ness of attributes from the document type, which you'd *hope* would have been set to one of the HTML doctypes (that define `id` as being an attribute of value type ID) by `loadHTML`.

(There is also [`Element.setIdAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setidattribute.php) which can be used to declare one instance of an `Attr` to contain an ID, but that's no use to you since you'd have to get hold of it first.)

I haven't tested this though and it wouldn't surprise me if PHP didn't implement this DOM Level 3 Core stuff properly. By my interpretation of [the spec for `isId`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Attr-isId), I reckon it should have picked up the `id` type definition already automatically. (My own DOM implementation certainly does.) But in that case your code would have worked. And I suppose `appendXML` is a non-standard method after all, so there's nothing to say it has to resolve type definitions like `loadXML` or `loadHTML` would.

So, maybe a workaround is a better plan. You might use a [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to select the element by `@id` attribute rather than real IDness as such. Of course this will be much slower than `getElementById`, but hopefully faster than `normalizeDocument`.

Or just lose the XML string-slinging and stick to the DOM methods, if you can; then it's trivial to keep a reference to a created element. (You can use helper functions to create the elements a bit more quickly if you find the DOM methods too wordy for the amount of content you're creating.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply bobince,

seems like normalizeDocument didn't do the trick.

I agree with you that sticking to DOM methods when adding new content would be best, but in this case it has to accept the strings, unless I build some recursive function to make proper DOM out of the string, but I guess it might end up using just as much resources as the reloading does now.

Comment: Yeah, shame... still, the XPath `//div[@id='newbox']` workaround should work OK. Assuming it works with a DocumentFragment as the context node, which it's supposed to but, again, I haven't tested on PHP... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know of that can handle that very well.. beautifuly is python's beautiful soup. The DOM is all split up into a parse tree which you can add to or take away at will mabey you can write a python script to handle the html and then coordinate the scripts by database or system call. alternatively server side javascript might be worth investigating.